# Logistic Regression - numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to create Logistic Regression from scratch using the Squared Loss function. However, I am having this error that I can't really figure out. The error is: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'. Any help will be much appreciated! (yes I know I got lazy with the coefficient.)

```
def logisticReg(data):
  X_train = [(d[0],d[1],d[2]) for d, _ in data]
  Y_train = [y for _, y in data]
  
  LogReg = LogisticRegression(random_state=42, solver='sag', penalty='none', max_iter=10000, fit_intercept=False)
  LogReg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  w=[round(c,2) for c in LogReg.coef_[0]]

  sigmoid = lambda y: 1/(1+np.exp(-y))
  classify = lambda y: 1 if y > 0.5 else 0
  F = lambda W, X: sum([w*x for w,x in zip(W,X)])

  for i in range(len(X_train)):
    Function = F(w,X_train)
    y_pred = sigmoid(Fucntion)
    Data_m = (-2) * sum(x*(y-y_pred)) 
    Data_b = (-2) * sum(y - y_pred)
    m = m- L*Data_m #update weights
    b = b-L*Data_b
  
  weights = zip(m,b)
  print(weights)

   
data = [((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 7), 0), ((1, -3, -2), 0), ((1, 8, 9), 1), ((1, 4, 3), 1), ((1, 5, -2), 1), ((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 6, 9), 1), ((1, 4, 2), 1), ((1, 1, -9), 1), ((1, -7, 7), 0), ((1, 0, -1), 1), ((1, 9, -4), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, -2, -5), 1), ((1, 2, 3), 1), ((1, -7, 2), 0), ((1, -3, 0), 0), ((1, 5, 0), 1), ((1, 0, -3), 1), ((1, -2, 3), 0), ((1, 9, 6), 1), ((1, 0, -8), 1), ((1, 0, 2), 0), ((1, -8, 6), 0), ((1, 1, 9), 0), ((1, 0, 5), 0), ((1, -4, 9), 0), ((1, 8, 2), 1), ((1, 2, 6), 0)] 
logisticReg(data)
```

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  There is useful information in there (including the line that raised the exception).

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the error occures on the call of function called *F*.

I fixed the problem by slightly modifying your code.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.linear_model as sk

def logisticReg(data):
    X_train = [(d[0], d[1], d[2]) for d, _ in data]
    Y_train = [y for _, y in data]
  
    LogReg = sk.LogisticRegression(random_state=42, solver='sag', penalty='l2', max_iter=10000, fit_intercept=False)
    LogReg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    w=[round(c,2) for c in LogReg.coef_[0]]

    sigmoid = lambda y: 1/(1+np.exp(-y))
    thresh = lambda y: 1 if y > 0.5 else 0
    F = lambda W, X: sum([w*x for w,x in zip(np.array(W), np.array(X))])

    for i in range(len(X_train)):
          res = F(w, X_train)
          y_pred = sigmoid(res)
#    Data_m = (-2) * sum(x*(y - y_pred))
#    Data_b = (-2) * sum(y - y_pred)
#    m = m - L*Data_m
#    b = b - L*Data_b
  
#  weights = zip(m,b)
#  print(weights)
    
    return(None)
    
    
data = [((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 1, 7), 0), ((1, -3, -2), 0), ((1, 8, 9), 1), ((1, 4, 3), 1), ((1, 5, -2), 1), ((1, 0, 0), 1), ((1, 6, 9), 1), ((1, 4, 2), 1), ((1, 1, -9), 1), ((1, -7, 7), 0), ((1, 0, -1), 1), ((1, 9, -4), 1), ((1, 1, 0), 1), ((1, -2, -5), 1), ((1, 2, 3), 1), ((1, -7, 2), 0), ((1, -3, 0), 0), ((1, 5, 0), 1), ((1, 0, -3), 1), ((1, -2, 3), 0), ((1, 9, 6), 1), ((1, 0, -8), 1), ((1, 0, 2), 0), ((1, -8, 6), 0), ((1, 1, 9), 0), ((1, 0, 5), 0), ((1, -4, 9), 0), ((1, 8, 2), 1), ((1, 2, 6), 0)] 
logisticReg(data)
```

However, you should rethink about what your algorithm should do because it seems unclear: you want to code the Logistic Regression algorithm from scratch but use the algorithm from *sklearn* to compute the value of the coefficients of the model for a given dataset and then you seem to use these coefficients in the *for* loop...

What you should do in your Logistic Regression function is compute the coefficients of the Logistic Regression model applied on a given dataset without using *sklearn* at all. And then you may call your own Logistic Regression on a given dataset to get the coefficients and compare them to those computed by the Logistic Regression from *sklearn*.

Useful link to documentation about logistic regression model fitting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Model_fitting